# How to get params and type definition for custom React/React-Native components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code

I built a custom React Native Input Component which shows a dark border at the bottom when focused but when I am using this component then I am not getting props suggestion provided by VS Code Intellisense.

```
function TextInputComponent(props) {
  const [controlledValue, setControlledValue] = useState('');
  const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);
  const {
    placeholder,
    onChangeText,
    autoCapitalize,
    ref,
    secureTextEntry,
    value,
    defaultValue,
    controlled,
    editable,
    ...rest
  } = props;
  return (
    <TextInput
      ref={ref}
      value={controlled ? controlledValue : value}
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      placeholderTextColor={globalColors.semiGray}
      autoCapitalize={autoCapitalize}
      editable={editable}
      mode="outlined"
      onFocus={() => {
        setFocused(true);
      }}
      onBlur={() => {
        setFocused(false);
      }}
      style={[
        styles.textInput,
        focused ? {borderColor: globalColors.blue} : {},
      ]}
      onChangeText={text => {
        if (controlled) {
          console.log(text.toLowerCase());
          setControlledValue(text.toLowerCase());
          onChangeText(text);
        } else {
          onChangeText(text);
        }
      }}
      {...rest}
    />
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textInput: {
    ...elementStyles.input,
  },
});
```

Is there any way I can get prop and type definitions without using TypeScript?

```
/**
 * 
 * @param {{header: string, subheader: string, imageAlt: string, contentList: Array, orderLink: Object, contentLink: Object}} props 
 */
```

I have seen @params way of definition but I just want to extend the default TextInput Definition not to write all the type definitions again for my custom component.

Comment: I define props with the use of types. simply defining a type via, for example: `type props = { name: string; value?: number }` and passing it to a arrow function of afunctional component `const Bar: React.FC<props> = (props) => { ... code ... return <>{... return  code ...}</> }` this way it is set in stone what variables it has to be added and what variables can be conditional (with the use of a `?`). IMO - simple, quick and ez. and best aprt - types can be eported and used by other componnets, or variables, AND even extened so the component can inherrit the type and add more to it.

Answer (score 0):

check [Prop-Types](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) . you can easily do prop checking with it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30910745)